# Adding NA's to specific portions of a replacement

Tags: r

I'm working with two vectors and a data frame:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "D")
y <- c(1, 3, 5)

df:
#  var1  var2
#1 ddAd  NA
#2 dBdd  NA
#3 ddCd  NA
#4 Dddd  NA
```

The result I'm going for is this:

```
df:
#  var1  var2
#1 ddAd  1
#2 dBdd  3
#3 ddCd  NA
#4 Dddd  5
```

Someone suggested the following approach:

```
z <- grep(paste(x, collapse="|"), df$var1, value = FALSE)
df$var2 <- y[z]
```

The problem I'm having with the the above approach is that my replacement has fewer lines than the data frame.  Is there an easy way to add NA's to the replacement so that they correspond to rows that don't have an "A", "B" or "D"?

Comment: try `df$var2[z] <- y[z]`

Comment: Yes, that worked for me.

Comment: To clarify, df$var2[z] <- y[z] is the one that worked for me.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  `df$var2[z] <- y` works.  
`df$var2[z] <- y[z]` doesn't.

Comment: The results for `df$var2[z] <- y[z]` were weird.  In my actual data frame, I also have a `row_number` variable.  `df$var2[z] <- y[z]` only filled in values for the several lines where the value for `var2` happened to match the value for `row_number`.

Comment: Does the modified one suggested by aichao works i..e. `df$var2[z] <- y`

Comment: yes, `df$var2[z] <- y` works.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the index in 'z' to subset the 'var2' on the `lhs` of `<`

```
df$var2[z] <- y
```